# WPF Banana-Like curve arrangement for buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, button

I am developing a relatively `unique WPF Application` in C#, and I need to programmatically arrange `my Buttons` (User can add and remove buttons) in a banana like curve next to my button like this:

[image: Picture]

I tried it with a `StackPanel`, but it always is in a rectangular form and I don't know how to write the algorithm for dynamically adding buttons with custom sizes to this.

tl;dr: Can anyone help me find out the algorithm to dynamically programmatically arrange Buttons in a banana-like curve?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to draw them programmatically or are they already specified and you only have to change the style ?

Comment: Make your own Panel and override ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride to put children where you want them. Use an exponential function to put elements where you want them

Comment: @NawedNabiZada The user drags files on them, and I get the bitmap from the file. So I have a bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I customized it for your needs.

All you need is a Canvas (`sc` in my case)

`private void calcPos(double radius) {
            int l = sc.Children.Count;
            double x, y;
            double radians = 90 / (l);
            double alpha = 0.0;
            int current = 1;
            foreach(Image i in sc.Children) {
                alpha = 90 - (radians * current);
                y = radius * Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * alpha);
                x = radius * Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * alpha);
                x = 300 - x; //Window Size
                y = 300 - y; //Window Size
                i.Margin = new Thickness(x,y,0,0);
                current++;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

Make your own Panel and use an exponential function to put elements where you want them. Something like this (didn't try it):

```
public class BananaPanel : Panel {

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {
        double totalX, totalY;

        foreach (UIElement element in Children) {
            element.Measure(availableSize);
            totalX += element.DesiredSize.Width;
            totalY += element.DesiredSize.Height;
        }
        return new Size(totalX, totalY);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
        if(InternalChildren.Count == 0) return finalSize;
        double maxValue = Math.Abs(InternalChildren.Count, 2);
        double ratioX = finalSize.Width / maxValue;
        double ratioY = finalSize.Height / maxValue;
        for(int i=0; i<InternalChildren.Count; i++) {
            UIElement element = InternalChildren[i];

            Point p = new Point(Math.Pow(i, 2)*ratioX, Math.Pow(i, 2)*ratioY); //using square here, so it won't be banana-like, use an exponential function

            element.Arrange(new Rect(p, element.DesiredSize));
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

In your XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourBananaItems, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <local:BananaPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```